# Issue registering bitbucket private repository with redhat openshift

Tags: bitbucket, openshift

I have private git repository hosted on [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com). Following the instructions [here](https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-5-hosting-repositories-bitbucket/) on openshift blog I'm trying to configure this repository on openshift but it is failing in step where you annotate the secret using openshift command line (oc) tool. Getting following error.

```
$ oc annotate secret/repo-at-bitbucket \'build.openshift.io/source-secret-match-uri-1=ssh://username@bitbucket.org/username/my-app.git'
The Secret "repo-at-bitbucket" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Invalid value: "\\'build.openshift.io/source-secret-match-uri-1": prefix part a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower
case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9
]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

Struggling to resolve this issue. Appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Graham - appreciate quick response. I'm new to this.

Actually found the solution to my issue. Tried the command without any single quote it worked fine or in other words following ran without any error

oc annotate secret/repo-at-bitbucket build.openshift.io/source-secret-match-uri-1=ssh://username@bitbucket.org/username/my-app.git

secret "repo-at-bitbucket" annotated

Comment: This is probably because you're using Windows, where single quotes are unsuitable for quoting parameters. So you actually had two problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a backslash before that opening quote. The backslash in the blog was there to represent a shell line continuation, as the command couldn't be shown all on one line. If you copy/pasted onto a single line, you should remove the backslash.

BTW, rather than using the annotation, you can now use the `--source-secret` option to `oc new-app` or `oc new-build`. Just reference the secret name using it, and don't bother with the annotation.